# Implement Spring Security Login via a POST /login API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm creating an app/web-page having its **own login/register view/page.**

My back-end service is in Java and using Spring Security to manage user's authentication.

**Basic Goal is (from an app):-**

1. Register a user via a `/register` API. (Register page already on client-side)
2. Display a login page (already on client-side).
3. Hit `/login` api to authenticate user with provided username and password. (provided in JSON POST request)
4. On success, return a cookie to be used for next actions/api calls to authenticate logged-in user.

Both Login & Register APIs are to enable as public.

Here's my spring security config

```
//all imports

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll() //to allow these urls
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                 // dont want Spring's Login page to get rendered
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login").and().rememberMe(); 
    }


    @Override
    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        //for HTTP Basic Auth - but needs to be removed to implement Cookie based authentications
        UserDetails userDetails = User.builder().
                username("admin").
                password(passwordEncoder.encode("admin")).
                roles("ADMIN").
                build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);

    }
}
```

My concern is that `loginProcessingUrl()` doesn't redirect my URL `https://<domain>/login` request to its mapped controller method which internally gets users from DB & validates.
Also `https://<domain>/register` POST api doesn't work, it ask for login every time.

Went through all Spring DOCs & tutorials but no one seemed to answer such cases.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: JSON post for the login `/login`won't work. it would be form data. Unless you want to have your own `/login` controller which accepts and you call the auth controller for the same

Comment: @Rajeev any example I can refer too? Is it strictly compulsory to use formData?

Answer (score 1):

`loginProcessingUrl("/path")` is the path that tells Spring security to process credentials. Note that this will not pass request to your Controller method.

What you should do to show your own login page instead of the default one is use `loginPage("/login")`. This is the GET request which returns an HTML page.

You may be interested in [AuthenticationSuccessHandler.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html)

Refer this [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.16.RELEASE/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#configuring-a-custom-login-page)

Comment: That's the thing, I dont want to GET html from server. I have my own html page on client app which calls `/login` POST